# Google DNS API & Gcloud Console Error

Tags: windows, google-app-engine, dns, google-api

I'm using gcloud console for windows and have enabled the Google DNS API in the developer console. I have authenticated from the gcloud console, but when I try to do anything with the DNS api, I get the following error message:

> {
>       "error": {
>           "code": 403,
>           "errors": [
>               {
>                   "domain": "usageLimits",
>                   "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your pro ject.",
>                   "reason": "accessNotConfigured"
>               }
>           ],
>           "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
>       } } ERROR: (gcloud.dns.managed-zone.list) ResponseError: status=403, code=Forbidden, reason(s)=accessNotConfigured
>   message=Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to
>   activate the API for your project.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things to look at including if you have **enabled billing** for your project. Follow the link for more information https://cloud.google.com/dns/getting-started

Comment: Thanks! I should have specified, but billing is enabled.